# Auth0 hooks post-user-registration edit user_metadata

Tags: auth0

I created a post-user-registration hook, in which i would like to save some information to user_metadata. However, I don't see the data being saved

```
/*
    @param {object} user.user_metadata - user metadata
*/
module.exports = function (user, context, cb) {
  // Perform any asynchronous actions, e.g. send notification to Slack.
  user.user_metadata = {
     "someinfo": "abcd"
  }

  cb();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
module.exports = function (user, context, cb) {
  var response = {};
  user.user_metadata.foo = 'bar';

  response.user = user;
  return cb(null, response);
};
```

worked fine for me.

For rules the [docs](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/current/metadata-in-rules#updating-user_metadata) say that you can't directly update the `user_metadata`. As described on the link you have to use the `updateUserMetadata` function after you set the new values. I am not sure if this applies to hooks too (probably not, since the `auth0` object is not defined on hooks).

p.s. Keep in mind that hooks only run for Database Connections, as outlined in the [docs](https://auth0.com/docs/hooks/extensibility-points/post-user-registration). Is there a chance you used an account based on social login?

Comment: So i found out that in order to update the metadata, you have to use the pre-user-registration-hook. It's counter-intuitive with the prefix "pre" as if the user has not been created yet